# React.js: useEffect() dependency freezes my app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to display modal when no products have been selected by user before. I ended up having an infinite loop of `useEffect()` dependency. I'm not sure how to do it correctly in React.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

const MyComponent = ({ products }) => {
    const [modals, setModals] = useState({});
    const [currentModalName, setCurrentModalName] = useState('');

    const setCurrentModal = useCallback(
        (modalName, data = {}) => {
            if (modalName) {
                setModals({
                    ...modals,
                    [modalName]: {
                        ...modals[modalName],
                        ...data
                    }
                });
            }

            setCurrentModalName(modalName);
        },
        [modals]
    );

    useEffect(
        () => {
            if (!products.length) {
                setCurrentModal('chooseProduct')
            }
        },
        [products, setCurrentModal] // setCurrentModal causes infinite loop
    );

    return (
        <div>...</div>
    );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

I can just remove `setCurrentModal` from the dependencies, but I'm warned about it. If I add it, my React app freezes.

How can I organize my code to avoid freezing?

Comment: Related: [How to fix missing dependency warning when using useEffect React Hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55854902/11838196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why it loops?

The callback is always changing since it depends on the `modals`, which is always a different object even though it has the exact same properties as before, which always triggers the `useEffect` since it depends on the `setCurrentModal` callback value, which is always different since `(() => {}) !== (() => {})`.

## Solution

**Always use the [*functional update*](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) when the current state is needed** to set the next state.

It'll prevent the need for the `modals` state as a dependency, which will limit the times when the callback is updated, fixing the infinite loop at the same time.

In addition to solving today's problem, functional update of the state is less prone to race-conditions, where multiple updates batched by React would overwrite each others.

```
const setCurrentModal = useCallback(
  (modalName, data = {}) => {
    if (!modalName) return; // precondition fail? early return.

    // Happy path here!

    // Note that I've used a different name to highlight that 
    // it's a different variable and to avoid shadowing the 
    // `modals` var from the outer scope.
    setModals((currentModals) => ({ // use functional update. 
      ...currentModals,
      [modalName]: {
        ...currentModals[modalName],
        ...data
      }
    }));

    setCurrentModalName(modalName);
  }, 
  // remove `modals` from the dependencies.
  // setter functions are stable anyway, so it should remove any warning.
  [setModals, setCurrentModalName]
);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!products.length) {
      setCurrentModal('chooseProduct')
    }
  },
  [products, setCurrentModal] 
);
```

Since the `setCurrentModal` callback is now stable (never ever changing), the `useEffect` will only be called when `products` value changes.

## Missing dependencies warnings

The missing dependencies warnings come from the [`eslint-plugin-react-hooks`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin), specifically, the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` rule. It's totally optional, but it helps keep the code clean and safe.

You could also choose to disable the warning just for this line:

```
const setCurrentModal = useCallback(
  (modalName, data = {}) => {
    // ...
    setModals(/* ... */);
    setCurrentModalName(modalName);
  }, 
  [] // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
);
```

Comment: The thing is, I'm still warned about missing `setCurrentModal` dependency in this case. I think it's because it's inside the functional component, so even though it's `const`, it will still change on the next cycle. I could move `setCurrentModal ` outside the component, except is uses the state.

Comment: @RoboRobok I've updated my answer with all relevant dependencies which should remove any warnings and fix the loop problem as well.

Comment: It says that `modals` is a required dependency too, unfortunately.

Comment: @RoboRobok it means that `modals` is still used inside your callback or effect and that you didn't implement correctly what's in my answer (which removes completely the `modals` state from the callback).

Comment: @RoboRobok, noticed the function in `setModals`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it at first. I had no idea I can use a state setter as a function! So as a rule of thumb, I guess it's always better to do it that way whenever I need to use the previous value to compute the new one - am I correct?

Comment: @RoboRobok yes, that's exactly the point of the solution I'm exposing above! I've linked to the documentation for more information on how and why functional update matters.

Comment: Awesomeness, thank you! Sorry I ignored some parts of your answer at first, I felt overwhelmed. Thank you for a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify it, without using useCallback.

(tested with Next.js and had no warnings, but if you still have some, you should use the answer of @Emile Bergeron)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const MyComponent = ({ products }) => {
  const [modals, setModals] = useState({})
  const [currentModalName, setCurrentModalName] = useState('')

  const setCurrentModal = (name, data) => {
    if (name) {
      setModals(prev => {
        return { ...prev, [name]: { ...prev[name], ...data }}
      })
      setCurrentModalName(name)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!products || !products.length) {
      const modalName = 'chooseProduct'
      const data = { data: 'data' }

      setCurrentModal(modalName, data)
    }
  }, [products])

  const modalsJsx = modals ? Object.keys(modals).map((x, i) => {
    return <li key={`modal-${i}`}>{x}</li>
  }) : ''

  const addModal = () => {
    const name = 'test' + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(300))
    setCurrentModal(name, { data: 'Hey' })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Current Modal : {currentModalName}</p>
      <p>Modals : </p>
      <ul>
        {modalsJsx}
      </ul>

      <button onClick={addModal}>Test</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyComponent
```

The function with useCallback to avoid warnings :

```
  const setCurrentModal = useCallback((name, data = {}) => {
    if (name) {
      setModals(prev => {
        return { ...prev, [name]: { ...prev[name], ...data }}
      })
      setCurrentModalName(name)
    }
  }, [setModals, setCurrentModalName])
```

Comment: But I'm using this logic of changing modals all over my component.

Comment: Just edited the code with externalized function

Comment: The warning is still there.

Comment: Yes, just edited the post with useCallback to prevent warnings